# Zend Framework: Module Name in Bootstrap _initNavigation

Tags: php, zend-framework, bootstrapping

I need to know how to get the current module name in the bootstrap _initNavigation() function of my zend application. On the load of the page I'm doing a request to a change navigation by module. The problem is that module name get in _initView() method by my code but module name not get in _initNavigation().

```
$this->bootstrap('frontController');
$req = $this->frontController->getRequest();
echo $req->getModuleName();
```

Answer (score 0):

This can't be done in the bootstrap. Routing hasn't yet occurred, so the application doesn't know what the current module is. You'll need to move this logic to a controller plugin instead.

Comment: Thanks @Tim Fountain for suggestion but i have 4 different modules in my application and i want to change navigation as per active current module. i want to set navigation file name from bootstrap _initNavigation so i required module name in bootstrap _initNavigation function.

Answer (score 0):

Try use getModuleName() method in bootstrap. That is return module name for current placed bootstrap (module or application)

This method placed in Zend_Application_Module_Bootstrap